# How to sell songs & play tracks in android app?

Tags: android, spotify, google-music

Is it possibile to play tracks and sell songs in an Android app using Google Play Music, Spotify or others? Are there any APIs for this purpose?

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved by using the correct [Intents](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html). You can obviously reverse-engineer those yourself. Have a look at [this](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.electricsheep.asi) for an app that can give you access to the manifest and the intents each app handles, but keep in mind that these might change. If you are serious about this, you should simply contact Spotify and Google about that, and see if you can even get a share of the profits as well :)

Comment: So your suggestion is to contact them? Why are you talking about intents and reverse engineering...